# python script, which outputs a redirect signal to point the browser to the target landing page

Tags: python, http, redirect

I am posting an html form to a python script. However, is there a way to do a return redirect("/thanks.html") which will allow the python script to run, and redirect the user to another URL.    The python script that is being posted too will go on to post to another python script. I tried ajax, and javascript. I could not both post data and redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning this html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.location="/thanks.html" #or whatever the url is
</script>
</head>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your python script should simply output a `Location` header in its response after it's done processing its work.

Read [HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), section 14.30.